# SELECT NOT NULL values without WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null

Is there a way to select not null values without a where clause?
i know it can be done like this

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM T
WHERE X IS NOT NULL
```

but Im wondering if there is a way to put the null 'filter' in the select clause without using the where

maybe something like this?

```
SELECT NOT_NULL(X), Y, Z
FROM T
```

Ty

Comment: You want to remove the WHERE token ? Why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no, there is no way, if you need to filter stuff out you need a WHERE clause. That said, you can change the values returned from null to something else by using ISNULL or COALESCE

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for COALESCE?

i.e

```
SELECT COALESCE(HasBananas, 'No') FROM Sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see one sane reason to do this, but you could filter through a JOIN clause if you really don't want a WHERE.

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM T
JOIN (SELECT null a) Q ON X IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not :) But WHERE is MUCH better.

The trick here is in JOIN `ON` condition where if you compare anything with `NULL` it is always `FALSE` even `NULL=NULL` is `FALSE`.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c497/9)

```
select * from t 
join 
(
select distinct x from t
) t1 on (t.x=t1.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if a value is NULL and return it as a boolean in your result, then you can use something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN X IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS XisNull,
       Y, 
       Z
FROM T
```

If you just want to filter, then use the WHERE statement. It has been created for it :-)